# Prove $\mathbb{E}\left[Z_j(t)| Z_i^\prime(t)\right]=\theta_{i,\,j}(t)Z_i^\prime(t)$ where $\theta_{i,\,j}(t)\geq 0$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Suppose $X$, $Y$ are independent centred normal random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^N$ such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left[X_{i} X_{j}\right] & \leq \mathbb{E}\left[Y_{i} Y_{j}\right] \text { for all } i \neq j \\
\mathbb{E}\left[X_{i}^{2}\right] &=\mathbb{E}\left[Y_{i}^{2}\right] \text { for all } i
\end{aligned}
$$

For $t\in \left[0,\,1\right]$, define
$$
Z(t)=\sqrt{\left(1-t\right)} X + \sqrt{t}Y.
$$
Then for every $i,\,j\in \left\{1,\,\ldots,\,N\right\}$ and $t\in \left(0,\,1\right)$, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Z_j(t)Z_i^\prime(t)\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[Y_{i} Y_{j}\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[X_{i} X_{j}\right]\right) \geq 0.
$$
Then prove $\mathbb{E}\left[Z_j(t)| Z_i^\prime(t)\right]=\theta_{i,\,j}(t)Z_i^\prime(t)$ where $\theta_{i,\,j}(t)\geq 0$.

---

I can only use the definition of conditional expectation to attack the problem. But I don't know how to write it explicitly.

Comment: Lookin for answer too.

Comment: What is $Z'$ here?

Comment: @d.k.o. $Z^\prime$ is the derivative of $Z(t)$ with respect to $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
Z_j(t) \\
Z_i'(t)
\end{bmatrix}\sim N\!\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
v_{11} & v_{12} \\
v_{12} & v_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\right),
$$
where $v_{11}=(1-t)\mathsf{E}X_j^2+t\mathsf{E}Y_j^2$, etc. [Thus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case),
$$
\mathsf{E}[Z_j(t)\mid Z_i'(t)]=\frac{v_{12}}{v_{22}}Z_i'(t).
$$
Now,
$$
\frac{v_{12}}{v_{22}}=\frac{1}{2v_{22}}(\mathsf{E}Y_iY_j-\mathsf{E}X_iX_j)\ge 0,
$$
as required.